# AWS SNS error - Invalid parameter while publishing message using aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sns

I am working with AWS SNS services and completed the initial setup as the AWS documentation. I just needed to test it using aws-cli. So I used the following command to publish a test message to SNS topic from my local PC.

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:test-notification-service" --message "Hello, from SNS"
```

However, I got stuck on the following generic error. It just says Invalid Parameter. I have configured the  ~/.aws/credentials as needed.

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: TopicArn
```

Comment: Can you see the topic if you run aws sns list-topics

Comment: what is you default region set to in AWS cli? It might be a issue due to cross region

Comment: you can use `aws configure get region` to see your default region set in AWS CLI

Comment: @DavidWebster yes, it shows the list of SNS topics.

Comment: @AatishSai ohh, it shows us-west-2. I just changed the defualt region to the same region as SNS topic, it works now. Thank you very much for the help. :)

Comment: @AatishSai but aws-cli could have raise a more genric error rather than showing just "invalid parameter" :(

Comment: @ChaminWickramarathna sometimes the error message are tricky on AWS CLI and I knew it since it happed to me aswell. I will post the solution as an answer. Feel free to mark as correct to help other if they stumble upon this question

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue is due to cross-region. You AWS-CLI default region might be different to the region your SNS service location.

Check your AWS-CLI location and make sure you are in the same region as your SNS.

To check your region in AWS CLI use:

`aws configure get region`

To configure your AWS region you can use the command:

`aws configure set region <region-name>`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html

Comment: If anyone using `aws-sdk` in NodeJS is facing this error, then check whether every initialization of the SDK has the same value for `region` in its `config` property.

Answer (score 8):

You can just add region parameter `--region us-east-1` to your command:

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:test-notification-service" --message "Hello, from SNS" --region us-east-1
```